# Convergence in measure implies a.e. convergence in countable case.

Tags: probability-theory

Consider $(\Omega,\mathit{F},\operatorname{\mathbb{P}})$, where $\Omega$ is *countable* and $X_{n} \to X$ in measure, so $\forall \epsilon > 0$ $ \exists N$ : $\forall n > N$ we have $\operatorname{\mathbb{P}(\{ w : |X_{n}(w) - X(w)| \ge \epsilon\})} \to 0$. So we want to show that $X_{n} \to X$ **a.e.** , i.e. $\operatorname{\mathbb{P}}(\{w : \lim_{n\to\infty}X_{n}(w) \ne X(w) \}) = 0$.

I've tried to use : let's denote $A_{n,k} = \{w : |X_{k} - X| \ge 1/n\}$ , so we can rewrite convergence in measure like (this is a place , where I have a doubt) $\operatorname{\mathbb{P}}$ $(\bigcup_{n \ge 1} \bigcap_{m \ge 1} \bigcup_{k \ge m}A_{n,k}) \to 0$. Now how can we rewrite the **a.e.** convergence in such terms?

Also I thought , where should we use countability ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$m(\{ x : |f_n(x)-f(x)|>\epsilon \})=\sum_{x : |f_n(x)-f(x)|>\epsilon} m(\{ x \}).$$

This already used countability. Now if the left side goes to zero then so does the right side. Show that this means that if $m(\{ x \})>0$ then $f_n(x) \to f(x)$.

Comment: Am I right that summing in right is countable. So we should have $\forall \epsilon > 0$ $\exists N :$ $\forall n> N$ for all singleton $x_{i}$ (acquired for relation with measure) $m({x})$ tends to zero?

Comment: That's mean that measure of points with difference is tends to zero, which give us the OP result?